# Is there a way to get the size of an existing widget?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get my UI to show two buttons with one slightly overlapping the other, in the middle of a full-width card.  Because a Stack will only be as wide as its non-positioned children, I added a non-positioned child of a SizedBox with width double.INFINITY to give me a canvas to place the buttons on, but I don't know what to put as the SizedBox height.  Ideally, I want this widget to size itself appropriately whether the user is on a phone or a tablet so I'd rather base the SizedBox height around the current size of the buttons instead of just hard coding a number.

Is there a way to find the size of a given existing widget?  If not, what is the way to determine the height for objects that need to look good on multiple screen sizes?

Example code:

```dart
new Card(
  child: new Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      new SizedBox(
        width: double.INFINITY,
      ),
      new Positioned(
        left: 1.0,
        child: getButtonOne(),
      ),
      new Positioned(
        right: 1.0,
        child: getButtonTwo(),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Comment: I found a better way to achieve my desired effect was to not use a Stack at all, just a row with the two buttons and put the overlapping button inside a Transform widget with a transform property of "new Matrix4.translationValues(-30.0, 0.0, 0.0)", but I'm still curious about the answer to my original question.

Comment: Hi! You can actually answer your own question. If you found an answer, please add it as an Answer. Easier to find than the comment above :)

Comment: I will in future. My comment isn't an answer to my question about how to get a widget size, though, which is why I just put it as a comment.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The short answer is no, because at the time of the build function the widgets haven't been laid out yet so they don't have a size.

The longer answer is that to achieve custom layout effects you can use a custom layout builder, though in your case that wouldn't help because a custom layout builder can't size itself to its children. The next level up is to just build a custom render object directly, which is just what Stack and Row and Column and so forth actually are. Then you can do whatever you want, layout-wise.